# Can We Shut Down a Azure HDInsight Cluster When Not In Use to Avoid Charge

Tags: hadoop, azure-hdinsight

I created a hadoop cluster in Azure HDInsight, however it does not seem to be any option for me to shut down the cluster when not in use, it has incurred charges over the past few days. Anyone knows if there is an option for doing so? It sounds rather silly that users have to continuously pay for the cluster when in effect most of the jobs run on a cluster are periodic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no option to stop an HDInsight cluster.

**Note:**  It is recommended to delete the cluster after running your job to cut down the cost.

I would suggest you to vote up an idea submitted by another Azure customer.

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217335-hdinsight/suggestions/7104546-add-a-feature-to-shut-down-an-hd-insight-cluster

All of the feedback you share in these forums will be monitored and reviewed by the Microsoft engineering teams responsible for building Azure.

**Reference:** [Azure HDinsight - Pause/shut down clusters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-administer-use-portal-linux#pauseshut-down-clusters)